# Can an Azverkan make use of MOM Implants?

Tags: rifts

Are Azverkan close enough to "human-like" to sucessfully undergo Mind Over Matter Conversion?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, an azverkan can get M. O. M. implants

[*Mindwerks*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/091621169X) (1994) says, "Few [azverkan] trust magic, bio-wizardry, or M. O. M. augmentation" (45). This means, for example, an azverkan crazy is rare but possible.

Comment: and the last place you want to get a M.O.M. implant is from Mindwerks :D especially as a non-human

Answer (score 0):

The default answer is **yes**, but I have found some of the quotes that will allow you to decide for yourself if they can get it. I would say it is very rare but possible.

Mindwerkz page 45:

> Few trust magic, bio-wizardry or M.O.M. augmentation.

MindWerkz Page 17:

> Humans, True Atlanteans, Altara warrior women, ogres, ores, elves, simvan, most D-bees, and most intelligent, mortal life forms in general, including brodkil and gurgoyles can be physically and/or psionically augmented by M.O.M. technology. Note: Like other bionic systems, practitioners of magic avoid them because the artificial devices interfere
>   with the use of magic. Many people avoid M.O.M. augmentation because of the terrible insanity and other side effects that come with them!
>
> M.O.M. implants and cybernetic systems will NOT work on most supernatural beings or creatures of magic.
>
> A good rule of thumb is that any creature that can perform any type of metamorphosis, change size, or other feats of shape changing (yes that includes dragons, werebeasts and changelings), can regenerate lost limbs, possesses natural magic powers (like faerie folk), or is clearly a supernatural or magic creature, then that being is ineligible for M.O.M. implants (they don't work and/or the body expels the artificial device).
>   If the creature cannot use bionics, it cannot get M.O.M. or psynetic devices either; both are just another type of cybernetic implant.

Mindwerkz page 21:

> All the same fundamental limitations that apply to Crazies (described previously) apply to psynetic augmentation. Only humans, True Atlanteans, Altara warrior women, ogres, ores, elves, simvan, mosthumanoid D-bees and mortal life forms in general, including brodkil and gurgoyles, can receive psynetic M.O.M. brain implants.